# counting delimited unique strings in a data frame in R

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I have a data frame as follows:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
b <- c("AA; AA; BC", "BC; DE", "AA; BC; BC", "DE; DE")
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I want to count the number of unique two-letter combinations in each string in column b. So the correct answer would be 2, 2, 2, 1.

If I create a vector outside of the df

```
test <- c("AA", "AA", "BC")
```

then

```
y <- length(stri_unique(test))
```

y correctly returns 2. But if I try to implement that in the df:

```
df <- mutate(df, new_column = length(stri_unique(df$b)))
```

It returns an integer of 1024 for every row, which is definitely not right; the right answer would be 2, 2, 2, 1. Trying to understand why it breaks like this. Have tried specifying sep = ";" but then I just get an error that 2 arguments are passed to length which takes one argument. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split the string at the delimiter, apply the `list` elements with `stri_unique` and get the `lengths` of the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)  
library(stringi)  
df %>% 
    mutate(new_column = lengths(map(strsplit(b, ";\\s*"), stri_unique)))
```

-output

```
# a          b new_column
#1 1 AA; AA; BC          2
#2 2     BC; DE          2
#3 3 AA; BC; BC          2
#4 4     DE; DE          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or by using Base `R`

```
df$Unq_count <-  unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$b, ";\\s"), function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

---

```
  a          b Unq_count
1 1 AA; AA; BC         2
2 2     BC; DE         2
3 3 AA; BC; BC         2
4 4     DE; DE         1
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option using `strsplit` + `uniqueN`

```
> setDT(df)[, uniqCnt := sapply(strsplit(b, ";\\s"), uniqueN)][]
   a          b uniqCnt
1: 1 AA; AA; BC       2
2: 2     BC; DE       2
3: 3 AA; BC; BC       2
4: 4     DE; DE       1
```